# Как вернуться к вводу данных, если допущена ошибка при вводе

Tags: c++

```
std::cout<<"\t"<<"Ваш класс       -   " ;
std::cin>>klass;
```

Comment: Надежнее всего читать данные построчно и анализировать данные во введенной строке. При ошибке затребуйте повторный ввод.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, если введено что-то не то - значит, сбросить поток, попросить ввести заново. Вот примерный набросок для целого числа в конкретном диапазоне (понятно, что для другого типа все может быть иначе):

```
int N;
for (;;) {
    std::cout << " Введите целое от min до max: " << std::flush;
    if ((std::cin >> N).good() && (min <= N) && (N <= max)) break;
    if (std::cin.fail()) {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cout << "Неверный ввод, повторите.\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Число вне допустимого диапазона значений. Повторите ввод.\n";
    }
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
}
```

Comment: +1. забавно видеть как варианты этого кода расползаются по сайтам stackoverflow :) У меня где-то был вариант оформленный в функцию...

Comment: @Swift Он у меня в редакторе шаблоном забит :) Иногда, когда фрилансишь помаленьку - экономит время :)

Comment: А зачем эта строка - std::cout << "Неверный ввод, повторите.\n";

Comment: А без этого вы поймете, что ввод был неверным? :)

Comment: А почему тогда оператор вывода не выводит на экран эту запись     std::cout << "Неверный ввод, повторите.\n"; а выводит else {
        std::cout << "Число вне допустимого диапазона значений. Повторите ввод.\n";

Comment: Ну сами подумайте! Первая - если вы вместо числа введете `$^%$^%` какое-нибудь; вторая - если это будет число вне диапазона...

Comment: Теперь ясно   почему.

Comment: Для Harry. Возможно ли заменить ввод целого от min до max путем присвоения значений типа min=5,max=7

Comment: @igorekvp А в чем проблема? https://ideone.com/8Z79Mt

Comment: Для Harry. Такая запись будет правильной?

Comment: Для Harry. Наверно после " ввести N",  cin>>N не нужен?

Comment: @igorekvp Простите, просто не могу понять, о чем речь, каком `cin>>N` и что вам непонятно...

Comment: Для Harry. Все получилось после того как добавил #include <limits>
#include <iomanip> . Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Да без проблем, обращайтесь! :)